# CompletetableFuture order of execution

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8

I am trying to understand the non-blocking callback nature of completableFutures in java

```
 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            //Thread.sleep(20000);
            System.out.println("supplyAsync Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return "str";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }


    }).thenApply(str -> {
        System.out.println("thenApply Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return str;
    }).thenApply(str1 -> {
        System.out.println("thenApply Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return str1;
    }).thenAccept(str3 -> {
        System.out.println("thenAccept Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    });
    System.out.println("Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

With the above code i always see the out as seen below

**supplyAsync Thread name ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1

thenApply Thread name main

thenApply Thread name main

thenAccept Thread name main

Thread name main**

This order seems to suggest main thread waits till execution of all the Futures thread. Isn't this indicative of being blocking.
I tried to add the Thread.sleep to supplyAsync method and output was

**Thread name main**

None of the print statements in futures thread seems to have been executed. My understanding of non-blocking is being able to print

**Thread name main
supplyAsync Thread name

ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1

thenApply Thread name main

thenApply Thread name main

thenAccept Thread name main**

If a similar code is executed in Javascript , the above console output would be possible

Is the above possible in Java?

Comment: Are you waiting for the future to complete?

Comment: You should try thenApplyAsnc too and check the behavior. thenApply method executes the supplied function synchronously on whichever the thread that calls it.

Comment: The main thread will not wait for the completion of the asynchronous operation triggered by `supplyAsync`. But it is still possible that it completes before the next `thenApply` invocation and then, the other operations will run in the main thread. Just run your code in a loop, three or four times, and watch the difference.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not blocking. By default completable future executes its task on `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` where common pool's threads are `daemon` thread that means. When the Main thread completes its execution the *`JVM will terminate all other daemon thread`* from the pool that's why in the second case you are seeing only *`Thread name main`.*

However, you can pass own executor to the completable future.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("supplyAsync Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("Is daemon Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
                return "str";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }

        }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)).thenApply(str -> {
            System.out.println("thenApply Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return str;
        }).thenApply(str1 -> {
            System.out.println("thenApply Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return str1;
        }).thenAccept(str3 -> {
            System.out.println("thenAccept Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
        System.out.println("Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

If you run the above code you can get the output like :

```
Thread name main
supplyAsync Thread name pool-1-thread-1
Is daemon Thread: false
thenApply Thread name1 pool-1-thread-1
thenApply Thread name1 pool-1-thread-1
thenAccept Thread name1 pool-1-thread-1
```